# How many matches are played?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, combinations

> A tennis club has $10$ couples as members. They meet to organize a mixed double match. If each wife refuses to partner as well as oppose her husband in the match, then in how many different ways can the match be arranged?

I made the teams using derangement theorem since making teams in this case is similar to putting $10$ letters in $10$ envelopes such that no letter goes into the correct envelope. So, the number of teams $=\text{D}_{10}=10!\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{1}{1!}+\dfrac{1}{2!}-\dfrac{1}{3!}+\ldots+\dfrac{1}{10!}\right)$

However, I can't figure out how many different matches will be played.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want every person to be in a game?

Comment: @dREaM Yes, I want every person to be in a game.

Comment: well, the number of ways you can make the games once the teams has been formed is not constant, it actually depends on how the teams where created.

Comment: I think the heading of the question is yours ? The question talks of **a** mixed doubles match (not **tournament**), and goes on to ask in how many ways can **the** match be arranged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I read it, the question talks about **"a"** ( = 1) mixed doubles match.

We can choose 2 ladies in **${10\choose 2}= 45$** ways, and since their husbands can't be in the match,

choose the gentlemen in **${8\choose 2} = 28$** ways

Having chosen the 4 who will play, there are only 2 possible pairings.

Thus # of ways the match can be organised  = **$45\cdot28\cdot2$ = 2520**

Comment: Oh! Even I didn't see that. The answer matches with that of my book. Thanks :)

Comment: Lol what? You told me everybody had to play.